# c# xml linq add element to an element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

i've been searching and trying for hours but i can't make it work. so i decided to ask a question here. kindly help me.

i have an xml something like this

```
<parent>
    <anothertag/>
    <body>
        <monitor value="3"/>
        <mouse value="5"/>
        <chair>
            <monoblock value="5"/>
        </chair>
    </body>
</parent>
```

and this is my desired xml output if possible

```
<parent>
    <anothertag/>
    <body>
        <anotherbody>
            <monitor value="3"/>
            <mouse value="5"/>
            <chair>
                <monoblock value="5"/>
            </chair>
        </anotherbody>
    </body>
</parent>
```

this is my code

```
string xml = "<parent>" +
                "<anothertag/>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<monitor value=\"3\"/>" +
                "<mouse value=\"5\"/>" +
                "<chair>" +
                "<monoblock value=\"5\"/>" +
                "</chair>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</parent>";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                var p = doc.Descendants("body").Elements();

                foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("body").ToList())
                {
                    item.Add(new XElement("anotherbody", p));
                }

                Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

and here is the output

```
    <parent>
  <anothertag />
  <body>
    <monitor value="3" />
    <mouse value="5" />
    <chair>
      <monoblock value="5" />
    </chair>
    <anotherbody>
      <monitor value="3" />
      <mouse value="5" />
      <chair>
        <monoblock value="5" />
      </chair>
    </anotherbody>
  </body>
</parent>
```

the output is redundant. how do i remove it?

the `p.Remove();`
remove all the elements. thank you

Comment: Why can't you use XML parser?

Comment: what xml parser @Prajwal ? i saw lots of example only using xml and linq, that's why im using it,

Comment: My bad, didn't check the code. :D

Comment: can you help me with my problem? thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("body").ToList())
{
      item.ReplaceAll(new XElement("anotherbody", item.Nodes()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in this line

```
 var p = doc.Descendants("body").Elements();
```

you should not be extracting the `.Elements()` from your descendants. Change the line to

```
var p = doc.Descendants("body");
```

and it should work. But keep in mind that `.Descendants()` will find all of the tags that match the name specified even if they are nested inside other tags.

This may be ok if the tag `<body>` only appears as a child of `<parent>`, if not it would be better to rewrite the line in question as follows

```
var p = doc.Elements("body");
```